# I got a error, using FCM as HTTP post

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

Error: The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token).
Error 401

Code of the HTTP post:

```
let headers: Headers = new Headers({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'key=' + this.apiKey
})
```

Comment: If you `console.log(this.apiKey)`, is it logging the correct value? (Also, sending `Access-Control-Allow` headers from the front end is the wrong approach-- this needs to be sent from the backend)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide is just the header which is defined inside your service file. The http post code should be like 'this.http.post(...)' inside your service file. You can see samples on angular official website: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Once you find the http post method, check if you have provided the authentification token. According to the code you provide, I'll say the token should be this.apiKey. Make sure your post method provided the token.